# Using specified regressors in glm() in R

Tags: r, statistics, glm

Question related to R, glm() function:

I have a dataset obtained as:

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)
```

which contains the variable 'y' (y is binary 0 or 1) and 60 regressors. Three of these regressors are 'avg','age' and 'income' (all three are numerical).

I want to use glm function for logistic regression, as below:

```
model <-glm(y~., data = mydata, family = binomial)
```

Can you tell me how I may proceed if I don't want to use the three specified variables (avg, age and income) in the glm() function, and  use only the remaining 57 variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply exclude those three variables from mydata before running glm().

Here I create some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata<-replicate(10,rnorm(100,300,50))
mydata<-data.frame(dv=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),mydata)

> head(mydata)
  dv       X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7       X8       X9      X10
1  1 268.6773 268.9817 320.4701 344.6837 353.7220 303.8652 282.9467 264.6216 245.6546 222.9299
2  1 309.1822 302.1058 384.4437 247.6351 394.7827 285.1566 375.1212 398.5786 208.6958 309.7161
3  1 258.2186 254.4539 379.3294 398.5669 269.8501 240.8379 326.4154 295.5001 349.7641 313.2211
4  0 379.7640 307.9014 283.4546 280.8184 280.4566 300.5646 327.1096 299.2991 299.4069 244.0632
5  0 316.4754 267.2708 185.7382 382.7073 279.1889 349.5801 293.1663 243.8272 270.0186 332.5476
6  0 258.9766 388.3644 424.8831 375.6106 281.2171 379.6984 243.1633 232.7935 291.1026 248.3550
```

If I run your specified model on the data as it is then I use all the variables on the right hand side:

```
model<-glm(data=mydata, dv~.,family=binomial(link = 'logit'))

> summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = dv ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8891  -1.0853  -0.5163   1.0237   1.8303  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -2.4330825  4.1437180  -0.587   0.5571  
X1          -0.0020482  0.0049025  -0.418   0.6761  
X2          -0.0059021  0.0046298  -1.275   0.2024  
X3           0.0123246  0.0047991   2.568   0.0102 *
X4           0.0024804  0.0046856   0.529   0.5966  
X5           0.0025348  0.0039545   0.641   0.5215  
X6          -0.0005905  0.0047417  -0.125   0.9009  
X7          -0.0001758  0.0040737  -0.043   0.9656  
X8           0.0042362  0.0041170   1.029   0.3035  
X9          -0.0007664  0.0042471  -0.180   0.8568  
X10         -0.0042089  0.0043094  -0.977   0.3287  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 138.59  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 125.11  on 89  degrees of freedom
AIC: 147.11

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Now I exclude X1 and X2 from mydata and run the model again:

```
mydata2<-mydata[,-match(c('X1','X2'), colnames(mydata))]

model2<-glm(data=mydata2, dv~.,family=binomial(link = 'logit'))
> summary(model2)

Call:
glm(formula = dv ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mydata2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8983  -1.0724  -0.4521   1.1132   1.7792  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) -4.8725545  3.6357314  -1.340  0.18019   
X3           0.0124982  0.0047930   2.608  0.00912 **
X4           0.0031911  0.0045971   0.694  0.48758   
X5           0.0015992  0.0038101   0.420  0.67467   
X6          -0.0003295  0.0046554  -0.071  0.94357   
X7           0.0003372  0.0039961   0.084  0.93275   
X8           0.0038889  0.0040737   0.955  0.33977   
X9          -0.0010014  0.0042078  -0.238  0.81189   
X10         -0.0041691  0.0042232  -0.987  0.32356   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 138.59  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 126.93  on 91  degrees of freedom
AIC: 144.93

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` ("everything") on the right side of the formula can be modified by subtracting terms:

```
model <- glm(y~ . - avg - age - income, data = mydata, 
     family = binomial)
```